# Populating variable using @Value annotation

Tags: spring-boot

How to get use @Value in following scenario

```
   application.properties
        file.number=select-1
        file.1.name=test
        file.2.name=abcd
```

now here is my code

```
 @Value("#{'${file.number}'.split('-')[1]}")
    private String filenumber;
```

the above will give me value as 1
now I want to use it in below variable to fetch file name

```
   @Value("${file.#filenumber.name}")
//  @Value("${file.$filenumber.name}")
// @Value("#{file.$filenumber.name}")
// @Value("${file.#filenumber.name}")
       private String choosenfilename;
```

Note: here I am trying to refer to variable filenumber. I have tried all the above commented options.

**my ultimate goal is to assign value test to the variable to choosenfilename**

Request someone to help me

Answer (score 0):

You could think about doing this with [@ConfigurationProperties](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) instead of `@Value`:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class Properties {
    
    private String targetFile;
    private Map<String, String> file = new HashMap<>();

}
```

(I renamed your `file.number` to `targetFile`)

You can now easily access `properties.file.get(properties.targetFile)` to get your target filename. You can inject the properties bean in any other bean as usual.

Don't forget to enable the properties parsing via `@EnableConfigurationProperties({AppProperties.class})`.